# ArcGIS API for JavaScript - Search widget with external geocode service

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

To be brief, I want to add to my Search widget new geocode service that is not exposed by the ArcGIS Server REST API (more precisely - OneMap REST API - https://docs.onemap.sg/). I wonder if it is possible to add this service as widget source using Locator object and how to do that.

Thanks for every advice.

Comment: I dont think so because your custom geocoder wont need the same input parameters neither will return the same output schema than the Esri geocoder. You will have to buid your own user interface using javascript